# Power tradeoff between buildscript and CI server

Tags: ant, jenkins, gradle, continuous-integration, bamboo

Although this question specifically involves Gradle and Bamboo, it really is a question about *any* build system (Ant/Maven/Gradle/etc.) and *any* CI tool (Bamboo/Jenkins/Hudson/etc.).

I was always under the impression that the purpose of a CI build is to:

1. Check out code from VCS
2. Run a buildscript (Gradle, etc.)
3. Deploy a binary (WAR, etc.) to an environment

Hence, all the guts and heavy-lifting (running automated tests, code analysis, test coverage, compiling, Javadocs, packaging, etc.) was all to be done from inside the buildscript.

But Bamboo seems to allow you to break this heavy-lifting out of the buildscript and into Bamboo itself. In Bamboo, you can add build stages and decompose the stages into tasks. Each task is something just as atomic/fundamental as an Ant task.

So it got me thinking: how much should one empower the CI tool? What typical buildscript functionality should be transferred over to Bambooo/CI? For instance, should I be compiling from a Gradle task, or from a Bamboo task? Same goes for all tasks/stages.

For some reason, I view this as the same problem as to whether or not to use stored procedures or put the data processing all at the application layer. What are the pros/cons of each approach?

Answer (score 2):

> TL;DR at the bottom

My experience is with Jenkins, so examples will relate to that.

One thing with any build system (be it `CI server` or a `buildscript`), is that it should be stable, simple and self-contained so that an untrained receptionist (with printed instructions and proper credentials) could do it.

### Ease of use and re-use

Based on the above, one would think that a buildscript wins. *Not always*. As with the receptionist example, it's about easy of use and easy of reproducibility.

- If a buildscript has interdependent build targets that only work in correct order, dependence on pre-supplied property files that have to be adjusted for the correct branch ahead of build, reliance on environment variables that no-one remembers who created in the first place, and a supply of SCM revision numbers that have to be obtained by looking at the log of the commits for the last month... This is in no way better than a Jenkins job that can be triggered with a single button.
- Likewise, a Jenkins workflow could be reliant on multiple dependant jobs, each being manually pre-configured before the build, and need artifacts uploaded from one place to another... which no receptionist will do.

So, at this point, a self-contained good buildscript that only requires `ant build` command to do everything from beginning to end, is just as good as a Jenkins job that only required `build now...` button to be pressed.

### Self-contained

- It is easy to think that since Jenkins will (at some point) end up calling at least a portion of a buildscript (say `ant compile`), that Jenkins is "compartmentalizing" the buildscript into multiple steps, thus breaking away from being self-contained.
- However, instead you should zoom out by one level, and treat the whole Jenkins job configuration as a single XML file (which, by the way, can be stored and versioned through an SCM just like the buildscript)

So, at this point, it doesn't matter if the whole build logic is inside a single buildfile, or a single XML job configuration file. Both can be self-contained when done right.

### The devil you know

In majority of cases, it comes down to what you know.

- Some people find it easier to use Jenkins UI to *visually* arrange their build workflow, reporting, emailing, and archiving (and for anything that doesn't fit as wanted, find a plugin). For them, figuring out a build script language is more time consuming then simply trying it in UI.
- Others prefer to know exactly what every single line of their build script does, and don't like giving control to some piece of foreign code obfuscated by UI.

Both points have merits from all sides [Quality-Time-Budget](http://programsuccess.wordpress.com/2011/05/02/scope-time-and-cost-managing-the-triple-constraint/) triangle

### The presentation

So far, things have been more or less balanced. However:

- My Jenkins will email a detailed HTML report with a link to a job page and send it straight up to the (non tech-savvy) CEO. He can look at the list of latest builds, along with SCM changes for each build, linking him to JIRA issues fixed for each build (all hyperlinks to relevant places). He can select the build with the set of changes that he wants, and click "install iOS package" right off his iPad that he just used to view all this information. Meanwhile I can go to the same job page, and review the build logs and artifacts of each log, check the build time trends and compare the parameters that were used between the failing and succeeding jobs (and I didn't have to write any `echos` to display that, it's just all there, cause Jenkins does that for you)
- With a buildscript, even if you piped the output to a file, would you send that to your (non tech-savvy) CEO? Unlikely. But wait, you know *this devil* very well. A few quick changes and hacks, couple Red Bulls... and months of thankless work (mostly after-hours) later... you've created a buildscript that will create and start a webserver, prepare HTML reports, collect statistics and history, email all the relevant people, and publish everything on a webpage, just like Jenkins did. (Ohh, if people could only see all the magic you did escaping and sanitizing all that HTML content in a buildscript). But wait... this only works for a single project.

So, a full case of Red Bulls later, you've managed to make it general enough to build any project, and you've created...

### Another Jenkins/Bamboo/CI-server

Congratulations. Come up with a name, market it, and make some cash of it, cause this ultimate buildscript just became another CI solution a la Jenkins.

---

### TL;DR:

Provided the CI-server can be configured simply and intuitively so that a receptionist could run the build, and provided the configuration can be self-contained (through whatever storage method the CI-server uses) and versioned in SCM, it all comes down to the Quality-Time-Budget triangle.

If you have little **time** and **budget** to learn the CI server, you can still greatly increase the **quality** (at least of the presentation) by embracing the CI-server's way of organizing stuff.

If you have unlimited **time** and **budget**, by all means, make your own Jenkins with the buildscript.

But considering the "unlimited" part is rather unrealistic, I would embrace the CI-server as much as possible. Yes, it's a change. However a little time invested in learning the CI-server and how it compartmentalizes or breaks into tasks the different parts of the build flow, this time spent can go a long way to increasing the quality.

Likewise, if you have **no time and/or budget**, figuring out the quirks of all the plugins/tasks/etc and how it all comes together will only bring your overall **quality down**, or even drag the time/budget down with it. In such cases, use the CI-server for bare minimum needed to trigger your existing buildscripts. However, in some cases, the "bare minimum" is no better than not using the CI-server in the first place. And when you are at this place... ask yourself:

> Why do you want a CI-server in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Personally (and with today's tools), I'd take a pragmatic approach. I'd do as much as feasible on the build side (clearly better from an automation perspective), and the rest (e.g. distribution of work across machines) on the CI server. Anything that a developer might want to do on his own machine should definitely be automated on the build level. As to the concrete steps you gave, I'd generally check out code from the CI server, and deploy binaries from the build. I'd try to make every CI job look the same, invoking the build tool in the same way (e.g. `gradlew ciBuild`).

> In Bamboo, you can add build stages and decompose the stages into tasks. Each task is something just as atomic/fundamental as an Ant task.

To some extent, this overlap in functionality is natural, as neither build tool nor CI server can assume existence of the other, and both want to provide as complete a solution as possible.

> For some reason, I view this as the same problem as to whether or not to use stored procedures or put the data processing all at the application layer.

It's not an unfair comparison, and hence opinions will be as diverse, contextual, and nuanced.

Disclaimer: I'm a Gradle(ware) developer.